# Modifying countdown() method to display parameters in VS ASP.Net Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, visual-c++

Task: Modify the code for Countdown() method so it starts counting down at the start parameter, ends at the end parameter, and displays the message parameter when the countdown is done.

Current code:   `[Route("[action]/{start}/{end?}/{message?}")] public IActionResult Countdown(int start, int end = 0, string message = "") { string contentString = "Counting down:\n"; for(int i = start; i >= 0; i--) { contentString += i + "\n"; } return Content(contentString); }`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1v0Jd.png)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what's your expected result. The current code works but it just do a loop and then output a string:

```
[Route("[action]/{start}/{end?}/{message?}")] 
public IActionResult Countdown(int start, int end = 0, string message = "") 
{ 
    string contentString = "Counting down:\n"; 
    for (int i = start; i >= end; i--) 
    {
        contentString += i + "\n"; 
    } 
    return Content(contentString); 
}
```

[image]

If you want to achieve a countdown timer, I think you should do it combined with your frontend, maybe you can provide us more information.